# Error when using Passport.js isAuthenticated() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, passport.js

I'm just doing some testing as I write some endpoints on my server, and I noticed something really weird. here are some test endpoints I wrote:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
}
router.post("/test1", (req, res) => {
  console.log("test1 endpoint reached");
  res.send("test1 endpoint works");
});
router.post("/test2", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  console.log("test2 endpoint reached");
  res.send("test2 endpoint works");
});
router.post("/test3/:tabId", (req, res) => {
  console.log("test3 endpoint reached");
  res.send("test3 endpoint works");
});
router.post("/test4/:tabId", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  console.log("test4 endpoint reached");
  res.send("test4 endpoint works");
});
router.put("/test5/:tabId", (req, res) => {
  console.log("test5 endpoint reached");
  res.send("test5 endpoint works");
});
router.put("/test6/:tabId", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  console.log("test6 endpoint reached");
  res.send("test6 endpoint works");
});
```

All the tests that don't use ensureAuthenticated pass (1,3,5) while the tests that use ensureAuthenticated fail (2,4,6). Now, I thought maybe isAuthenticated() just doesn't work, but I have an actual endpoint which uses ensureAuthenticated and it works perfectly fine:

```
router.put("/updatePin/:tabId", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  const accountId = req.user.accountId;
  const tabId = req.params.tabId;
  const isPinned = req.body.isPinned;

  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { accountId: accountId, "tabs.tabId": tabId },
    { $set: { "tabs.$.isPinned": isPinned } },
    { new: true }
  )
    .then((updatedUser) => {
      if (!updatedUser) {
        throw new Error("User not found or tab not found");
      }
      res.json("Tab pin status updated!");
    })
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
});
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this might be the case? If further code is needed, please let me know.

Comment: What is in `req.isAuthenticated`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  next('Not authenicated');
}
```

Note the `next` call after the `if` block